# Tkinter Enter and Motion bindings

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to track what widgets I enter with my mouse into while it's pressed?
I want to create a chain-like effect that the background of the label\button change while click and drag the mouse and moving from widget to widget.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to the `<B1-Motion>` event, and then use `winfo_containing` to get the widget under the cursor.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

current_label = tk.Label(root, text="", anchor="w", width=100)
current_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")

def show_widget(event):
    widget = event.widget.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    current_label.configure(text=f"widget: {str(widget)}")

for x in range(10):
    name = f"Label #{x+1}"
    label = tk.Label(root, text=name)
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    label.bind("<B1-Motion>", show_widget)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done stuff like tracking entry/exit for a specific widget:

```
widget.bind("<Enter>", enter_func)
widget.bind("<Leave>", exit_func)
```

you may be able to do something cute with that

Comment: the problem is that once I click on a widget the event kind of "locked" on that widget, and the other widgets won't react correctly to the "<Enter>" bind